# VS Code Error - command 'PowerShell.SelectPSSARules' not found

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Just looking through at how Code can be used to edit PS scripts.

One feature that I am looking to investigate is the Script Analyser but when I do a Ctrl-Shift-P and select ">Powershell: Select PSScriptAnalyzer Rules" I get the error - "command 'PowerShell.SelectPSSARules' not found"

I have added the powershell.scriptAnalysis.settingsPath value to my user settings and created the pssa-settings.psd1 file which contains nothing but

@{}

Where are I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the [Powershell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed and loaded in order to successfully call the `PowerShell.SelectPSSARules` command.

These steps will load the extension once installed:

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Add new file (`Ctrl+N`)
3. Set language mode to Powershell (`Ctrl+K,M`, select `Powershell`)
4. Now you can start the PSScriptAnalyzer Rules command (`Ctrl+Shift+P` and  type `Powershell: Select PSScriptAnalyzer Rules`)